# AngularJS $compile HTML from templateURL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

There is the following way to add HTML dynamically in AngularJS

```
   var template = '<div>{{value}}</div>';
   var element = angular.element(template);
   placeholder.replaceWith(element);
   $compile(element)($scope);
```

Is it possible to do the same from templateURL or load template separately? (with standard mechanism so that it is cached in $templateCache)

Answer (score 22):

Sure, you simply use `$http` service to fetch the template and than compile and insert it manually. `$http` service will take care of caching implicitly.

<kbd>[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/ImHdCefAwau27r0lOvAh?p=preview)</kbd>

(Simplest) directive:

```js
app.directive('message', [
  '$http',
  '$compile',
  function($http, $compile) {
    var tpl = "template.html";

    return {
      scope: true,
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.message = attrs.message;

        $http.get(tpl)
          .then(function(response){
            element.html($compile(response.data)(scope));
          });
      }
    };

  }
]);
```

View:

```html
<span message="Hi World!"></span>
<span message="My name is Angular."></span>
```

Directive template (`template.html`):

```html
<span>{{message}}</span>
```

Comment: Also it will be better if you use $templateCache service to cache the template.

Comment: To handle all these details ($templateCache) automatically, just use $templateRequest.

Comment: Thanks, before i use `$rootScope` and  it was really slow. now fixed.